# Call WCF - Host from Windows application

Tags: c#, wcf

I have 4 projects in my solution. 2 WCF Service Library projects called `GetDetfromDB`, `ModifyDBService`, one console application which has reference of these WCF service libraries and a windows application to call this WCF Service.

I made the reference of the console app in windows app. Now I am able to call the client app from window app.

But now how can I invoke the services which are referred in console app by calling from windows app?

Note: When I press F5 or Debugger-->Start new instance both service runs correctly from my console. I configured all the binding,endpoints address correctly. I want how to call it programmatically.

Here is my console application code:

```
namespace ServiceHostConsole
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("enter to start");
            Console.Read();

            Type serviceType = typeof(GetDetfromDB.ImpService);
            Type serviceModifyDB = typeof(ModifyDBService.Manipulate);

            ServiceHost host1 = new ServiceHost(serviceModifyDB);
            host1.Open();

            using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(serviceType))
            {
                host.Open();

                Console.WriteLine("The Product Service is available");
                Console.ReadLine(); host.Close();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter to close modify service");
            Console.Read();
            host1.Close();
        }

        public string returnPath()
        {
            string folder = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            return folder;
        }
    }
}
```

From Windows application I am calling like this ....

```
 public Form1()
 {
      InitializeComponent();

      ServiceHostConsole.Program pb = new ServiceHostConsole.Program();
      Process.Start(pb.returnPath()+ @"\ServiceHostConsole.exe");
 }
```

Now I am getting the following error when program tries to open my service..

> Service 'ModifyDBService.Manipulate' has zero application
>   (non-infrastructure) endpoints. This might be because no
>   configuration file was found for your application, or because no
>   service element matching the service name could be found in the
>   configuration file, or because no endpoints   were defined in the
>   service element

I am suspecting that I am calling blindly the method only and not invoking the service.

Kindly help me to get out of this issue, I have been struggling for the past 5 days for this.

I need to publish my windows application and when i click setup both my windows application and client application with invoked services should open. This is my requirement.

My App.config of ServiceHostConsole look like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="GetDetfromDB.ImpService">
                <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/MyService" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                    bindingConfiguration="" contract="GetDetfromDB.IGetExpenseValuestype" />
            </service>
            <service name="ModifyDBService.Manipulate">
                <endpoint address="http://localhost:8081/MyService1." binding="basicHttpBinding"
                    bindingConfiguration="" contract="ModifyDBService.IManipulateDB" />
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What does your `app.config` for the ServiceHostConsole application look like? We need to see everything inside the `<system.serviceModel>` tag

Answer (score 2):

Do not reference the WCF service libraries. They should only be referenced from the projects which host the services.

Instead, you should use "Add Service Reference" to reference the *services*.

See "[How to Consume a Web Service](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/)".